# What is the xslt mode binding for a choice field?

Tags: xslt

Say I want to grab a choice field via xsl.  What is the right binding for `mode`?  I can't find this information *anywhere*, and I've tried *everything* in its place!

- `Text_body`  ?
- `Choice_body`  ?
- `MultiChoice_body`  ?

  ```
  <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='myChoice']" mode="Choice_body">
      <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
      <td class="someclass">{$thisNode/@myChoice}</td>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

Does anyone have a clue?

[*Later...*] It's been awhile now, I guess this is a hard question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to define [Custom Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx) for a [SPFieldChoice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice.aspx) in template for `mode` attribute should be used value **body**

For example, if we apply for Tasks list that contains *Status* field ([SPFieldChoice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice.aspx)) the following XSLT style sheet

```
<xsl:template match ="FieldRef[@Name='Status']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Status='Not Started'">
                <img src="/_layouts/images/tasknotdone.gif"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Status='In Progress'">
                <img src="/_layouts/images/taskpane.gif"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Status='Completed'">
                <img src="/_layouts/images/taskdone.gif"/>
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Status" />
            </xsl:otherwise>                
        </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

the List View will be rendered as shown below

[image]

Hope this helps,

Vadim

Comment: Hey!  That did it! +1 solved!  However, I like to use css, so instead of `img` tags, I inserted: `<span class="statusRating3"></span>` and then used my css to insert the icons as background images.

Comment: Glad it helped:)